# Multiple Ecore/EMF models in Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, emf

Begin relative new to EMF I can only give sketch of what I want to do. The end product is a eclipse plug-in that have access to at least two EMF models. The first model is created by using Xtext to defined DSL. The second EMF is created using xtend code based on a ecore model.

My questions:

- How to create a ecore model that will be visible in the plug in?
- How to create an EMF instance of the ecore model using java/xtend when the code is executed in the plug in. The code snippets I find look like

  val resourceSet = new ResourceSetImpl
  val resource = resourceSet.getResource(URI.createURI(file), true)

but have no idea what the value of `file` must be to reference the ecore model.

- any suggestion of how to translate the one EMF model to the other EMF model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If I understand correctly, what you want to have is a model in your plug-in that's deployed in your end product. In that case you probably want to look at "platform:/plugin/..." URIs which you can probably use to retrieve artefacts from the running platform.
- See [URI.createURI(String)](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.4.3/org/eclipse/emf/common/util/URI.html#createURI(java.lang.String)) although you may want to look at URI.createPlatformPluginURI in your case
- Search for Model-to-Model transformations, which you can specify with a variety of technologies (including Java, Xtend, ATL, etc.)